# Form with hidden field not submitting

Tags: python, django

I have the following form in django

```
forms.py

class CtForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model       = Contact
        fields      = ["name", "email"]
        # widgets     = {'cid': HiddenInput()}



models.py

class Contact(models.Model):
    cid             = models.ForeignKey(Cr, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    email           = models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

I have the form displayed in a template, and everything displays good and no issues there, the issue is when i submit the form, i get the following error:

```
(Hidden field cid) This field is required.
```

But if i remove the

```
widgets     = {'cid': HiddenInput()}
```

from the forms.py it works perfect, any way to make this work without displaying the cid in the template?

```
views.py

def create_contact(request, cid):

    cr = cr.objects.get(id=cid)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CtForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.cid_id = cid

            form.save()
            
            return render(request, 'create_contact.html', {
                'form': form,
                'cr': cr,
            })
    else:

        form = CtForm(None)

        return render(request, 'create_contact.html', {
            'form': form,
            'cr': cr,
        })
```

Template code being used

```
<form method="post" action="" novalidate>
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <tbody>
                            {{ form.as_table }}
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Create"> </td>
                        </tbody>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Can you share the view (both in the GET and POST direction)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to include the `cid` in the form, it is already in the URL. We thus can exclude it from the form:

```
class CtForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'email']  # 🖘 no cid
```

in the view, we then inject the `cid`, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect


def create_contact(request, cid):
    cr = get_object_or_404(Cr, id=cid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CtForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.cid_id = cid
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = CtForm()
    return render(request, 'create_contact.html', {'form': form, 'cr': cr})
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and that awesome explanation

Comment: One quick thing, i just tested the code, and it inserts something in the db but its all blank, doesn't put in the actual data

Comment: @PeanutGallery: can you edit the question with the test you've made? Or the template you use for rendering?

Comment: i modified the questions, showin the template and changes i made

Comment: @PeanutGallery: remove `action=""`.